# Vue - Change in the state does not re render the template?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to understand the basics of Vue and so far what I understand is every time any of the states in the data property changes, the template or the component should re render. Here is the code snippet I'm working with.

**index.html**

```
<div id="app">
  <h3>Generator</h3>
  <div>
    Input: 
    <input @input="onInput"/>
  </div>

  <div>
    Output: 

    {{test()}}

  </div>
</div>
```

**main.js**

```
new Vue({
  el:'#app',
  data: {
    textInput: ''
  },
  methods: {
    onInput(event){
      this.textInput = event.target.value
    },
    test(){
      console.log("Test running")
    }
  }
})
```

***What I expected to happen?***

Since I'm updating the `textInput` data property with every keystroke, I thought that since the template would re render itself, I would see the `Test running` message in the console every time I hit a key and since the page would re render every time, I would see the input field as blank.

***What currently happens***

1. I see the `test` function run only once when I run the code.
2. I don't see a blank input field with every key stroke

Comment: Right now is not re-rendering because it is not binded to any DOM element. Can you elaborate more on what are you trying to achieve?. You want to a dom element re-render on each key stroke?

Comment: [See: The vue instance ](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Data-and-Methods)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DOM does not depend on `textInput`, so changes to it do not cause a re-render. If the render function uses the variable, you will get a re-render when the variable changes.

```js
new Vue({
  el:'#app',
  data: {
    textInput: ''
  },
  methods: {
    onInput(event){
      this.textInput = event.target.value;
    },
    test(){
      console.log(this.textInput);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <h3>Generator</h3>
  <div>
    Input: 
    <input @input="onInput"/>
  </div>

  <div>
    Output: 
    {{textInput.length}}
    {{test()}}

  </div>
</div>
```